# Why JQuery is not working when DOM changes are made even after .on delegation method

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, delegation

I have a jquery function that swaps a bootsrap dropdown to a dropup, if the distance from the element to the bottom of the window is smaller than the height of the dropdown menu. It works fine, until the DOM gets updated and something gets added to the bottom of the window (let's say a new section or some menu gets expanded). The new distance from the element doesn't get accounted. I tried delegation with the .on method to check if the DOM gets updated but that did not fix the issue.

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', function(){
  var elemDistanceToBottom = $(window).height() - $(this).offset().top;
  if($('.dropdown-menu').height()>elemDistanceToBottom ){
     $(this).closest(".dropdown-fix").addClass("dropup");
  }
});
```

Comment: You're not delegating, if you use this form. You need to pass three parameters to use the event delegation

Comment: The widow.height is being changed and that is the main problem, it is not being detected

Comment: Check the dupe. To use event delegation, you have to select a *parent* element, then as the second parameter of `on` pass the selector you want to monitor. So, if you have a dynamically added `.child` and a `.parent`, you need to do `$(".parent").on("click", ".child", function() {})`. If you do `$(".child").on("click", function() {})` that will only bind the handler to the elements that exist at the time you make that call, it does not account for dynamically added `.child` elements.

Comment: As this question isn’t really about event delegation at all, this seems like a more appropriate dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom